# People outside my local network cant connect to my server, even after port forwarding

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, hosting

[image]

I have added the port to my router.

[image]

And added port 25565 to my firewall, and contacted my ISP, i added 192.168.0..169 as a static ip for my pc where the minecraft server is hosted.

When someone trys to join by using publicip:25565 they get discornected and get a error message "Connection Refused".

I dont know what to try.

Comment: Minecraft Java is outside my expertise, but I can give you a few pointers: IP addresses can change over time, so you might want to give your server a fixed IP so it's always 192.168.0.169. As for your public IP, you can try and use a DDNS (Dynamic DNS), so people can find your server using a domain name instead (e.g. myminecraftserver.com). Your device will contact the DDNS server regularly, so it always knows your current public IP. Your router's manufacturer might offer a free DDNS service supported by your router. Finally, check if your firewall allows Minecraft to listen to port 25565.

Answer (score 1):

Add an exception to your firewall or temporarily turn it off.

Port forwarding allows for other devices outside the network to attempt connections to a device within your network - but that does nothing when your device refuses the connection.